# Displaying multiple RTSP stream using MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, libvlc

I am trying to create an app that plays videos using `RTSP`, with the use of `VLCKit`.

I currently can play video without issue, but, the RTSP i'm using has multiple streams and I have to play them simultaneously. Is this possible? Been playing around with `currentVideoTrackIndex` but it always return -1. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Try with multiple mediaplayers?

Comment: Can you do it with VLC?

Comment: on desktop VLC, yes. but on mobile version no. I got stuck on this with using the SDK.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: you have multiple URLs for multiple streams right?

Comment: uhh no. I only have 1 URL, the said url has multiple stream. e.g. Cam-01, Cam-02, ...

Comment: Can you share the URL? Also, try enabling verbose logs in VLC app before you play it to see what it does. Might give you some clues